# user defined warning in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to add code just temporary and remove it before I do commit. How to create user defined warning in typescript so compiler (or build server) will let me know that this code is still there. I don't want to forget about it. In C# there is #warning, is there something similar in TypeScript?

Example:

```
foo(){
    // #warning: remove next line before commit, it is just for develop purposes
    return true;
    return someLogic(); // just this line should be there
}
```

Comment: In general, this is a bad idea. You should use external configuration (e.g. looking for a `DEVELOPMENT` environment variable) to toggle the behaviour, otherwise you have to keep editing the file just to run unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since type errors don't block code generation, you can write a dummy line of code that produces a type error, for example:

```
let a: "remove me before commit" = "";
```